# CSS: Image and text with inset shadow aligned inside a link (display:block) with gradient background

Tags: css, html, gradient, shadow

Ciao,

I'm working on a web app and I'm trying to obtain a clickable div (which I realized with a `<a href...>` styled as "display: block" in css with a linear gradient.
No problems...

Then I wanted to insert an icon inside this `<a...>` and I did it with a `<p>` containing an iconic font...
Again no problems...

Then I tryied to insert some different text in calibri below that icon/font inside the same  block and with the same style (I wanted to have an inner shadow that makes things look like they are "pressed").
Here I'm not satisfied about the results because I can hardly align these 2 elements (which I styled as `<p>`, should have I used `<span>` instead?).

As an example I'd like to obtain an effect similar to the facebook app button but with image and text aligned vertically

[Facebook div/link](http://www.inghub.com/otherDownloads/FacebookDiv.png)

How can I do it? What is the best practice (iconic font + font or image styled in photoshop + font styled in css, or what?)?

PS: And what about the nice 2 lines as border of that link/div, how are they styled?

Comment: Could you post some snippets of your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best - image styled in photoshop + font styled in css
For lines try to play with gradients and box-shadow. http://jsbin.com/esasan/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <ul class="lines">
      <li class="line"></li>
      <li class="line"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

.main {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:70px;
  background: #fcfcfd; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfd 0%, #eaecf2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fcfcfd), color-stop(100%,#eaecf2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfd 0%,#eaecf2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfd 0%,#eaecf2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fcfcfd 0%,#eaecf2 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fcfcfd 0%,#eaecf2 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfcfd', endColorstr='#eaecf2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lines{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:64px;
  margin-top:3px;
}

.lines li {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:4px;
}

.line {
  width:2px;
  height:60px;
  background: #9fa0a3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #9fa0a3 0%, #f4f6fc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#9fa0a3), color-stop(100%,#f4f6fc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #9fa0a3 0%,#f4f6fc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #9fa0a3 0%,#f4f6fc 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #9fa0a3 0%,#f4f6fc 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #9fa0a3 0%,#f4f6fc 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9fa0a3', endColorstr='#f4f6fc',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
  margin-right:60px; 
}
```